# Checking if all textboxes in a panel a filled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I currently work on a Windows Forms application and I have 2 Panels with textboxes in them and I need to check the panel's textboxes separately if they are not empty, so it is not an option to loop through all the controls in the form.

```
            foreach (Control child in this.Controls)
        {
            TextBox textBox = child as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Text box can't be empty");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why not loop through the `panel.Controls`?

Comment: You can still loop through the controls... Just check if the `Control` in each iteration is a `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
    foreach(Panel pnl in Controls.OfType<Panel>())
    {
        foreach(TextBox tb in pnl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Text box can't be empty");
            }
        }
    }
```