# Issue with presence check of text boxes in a panel C# - Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms

For a game I have been developing, I am trying to do presence checks on all text boxes in a panel.

Before we go any further, here is my code:

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        foreach (Panel pnl in Controls.OfType<Panel>())
        {
            foreach (TextBox tb in pnl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please give an answer for all questions!");
                    okFlag = false;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    okFlag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (okFlag == true)
        {
         //Check answers below
```

The issue I am having is that even if I have values in all text boxes, the MessageBox will still show, "Please give an answer for all questions.

**okFlag** is a boolean which I have initialised as **true** at the top of my code.

I should also note that I have multiple panels with text boxes in them but all other panels are hidden when one panel is showing.

[This is the source where I got the code for this from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496873/checking-if-all-textboxes-in-a-panel-a-filled)

In conclusion, my issue is that the presence check on my text boxes aren't working as it seems to think that the text boxes are null or empty even when I do have values in them.

Comment: Have you stepped through this code to see what `tb.Text` actually contains when it shows the messagebox?

Comment: If a panel is hidden then you'd surely would not want to complain about its controls.  Use its Visible property.

Comment: P.Brian.Mackey, I just tried that and it is showing that there are values in the text boxes whenever I have values in the text boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have multiple panels with text boxes in them but all other panels are hidden when one panel is showing.

Since your code does not differentiate between visible and hidden panels, the only explanation for getting the message that you see is that some of text boxes in a hidden panel are empty.

You can fix this by checking `Panel`'s visibility in a loop:

```
foreach (Panel pnl in Controls.OfType<Panel>().Where(p => p.Visible))
{
    foreach (TextBox tb in pnl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text.Trim()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please give an answer for all questions!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is no need to use `okFlag`, because when you set it to `false`, your loop terminates early on the `return` statement anyway. In other words, there is no way to reach the end of the outer loop when `okFlag` is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

When you have got multiple panels and only one is visible your check will exit at the first invisible panel due to the textbox would have no text (it is invisible).

In your code you should check if the panel is visible:

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        foreach (Panel pnl in Controls.OfType<Panel>())
        {
            if(!pnl.Visible) 
               continue;

            foreach (TextBox tb in pnl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please give an answer for all questions!");
                    return;
                }
            }
...
```

Comment: Why would the `Panel.Visible` have anything to do with the `Textbox.Text` property?

Comment: @Ron Beyer Thinking about, that only the visible panel can be filled from a user - the invisible panels textboxes will have no text.

Answer (score 1):

you mentioned:

> I have multiple panels with text boxes in them but all other panels
>   are hidden when one panel is showing

Just because a control is hidden doesn't mean it isn't still available in the Controls collection. Perhaps you should also be checking the visibility state before checking that panel's controls.

```
    foreach (Panel pnl in Controls.OfType<Panel>())
    {
        if (pnl.Visible) {
            foreach (TextBox tb in pnl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please give an answer for all questions!");
                    okFlag = false;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    okFlag = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```